# Why empty lines are being printed at the when I use BufferedReader to read characters from the console and print them?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, file-handling, java-io

Here is my program.

// Here we use a BufferredReader to read characters from console.

```
package fileIO;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class BRRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        char ch;
        
        System.out.println("Enter characters, 'q' to quit.");
        do {
            ch = (char)br.read(); 
            System.out.println(ch);
        } while(ch!='q');

    }

}
```

Input 1: testq

Output:

t

e

s

t

q

Input 2: test

Output:

t

e

s

t

""

""

""

""

where "" means empty line.
My question is why 4 empty lines are printed for the case when the input characters doesn't contain letter 'q' but aren't printed when the input characters contain letter 'q'?

Comment: Because you are printing the carriage return and line feed without checking for them first; ditto `'q'`; and ditto for end of stream (`read()` returns -1). If you want to get rid of them, either filter them out explicitly or use `readLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Complete-er answer at the bottom**

Haven't run it at all to check, though it seems like it could have something to do with the use of a `do-while` loop instead of a `while` loop

This format will make sure that the character `'q'` is not read before it attempts to output anything

```java
while(ch!='q')
{
    System.out.println(ch);
    ch = (char)br.read(); 
}
```

And this format prints the read character before testing if it is valid

```java
do {
    ch = (char)br.read(); 
    System.out.println(ch);
} while(ch!='q');
```

**EDIT after some trial/error**

With this version, I have used the `Scanner` class which is quite similar, and I am more familiar with it. It may go something like so:

- Create Object(s) for reading the data `BufferedReader`,`Scanner`,etc.
- Check if there is content present
- Accept the data as a `String` and read the first character
- Output if the `String` is is not `q`
- Cycle the test-> read -> print -> loop, till `q` is entered

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter characters, 'q' to quit.");
String read = input.nextLine();
while(read.length() <= 1 && read.charAt(0) != 'q')
{
    System.out.print(read);
    read = input.nextLine();
}
```

**The (almost) original method***

Eureaka!

- name.read() Reads a single character --
  However, this returns an `int` datatype which cannot be converted with the `(char)` mask.
- name.readLine() Reads a line of text -- With this, you can simply take the character at index 0

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

```java
do {
    full = br.readLine(); 
    System.out.print(full);
} while(full.length() <= 1) && full.charAt(0) != 'q');
```

Not sure what the best way to do it would be between a `do-while` and a `while` loop, and that may ultimately come down to use case and opinion. and you may want to make a `boolean` method too

```java
// true if String matches 'q' or "quit"
public static boolean isQuit(input)
{
    String lowercase = input.toLower();
    char start = input.charAt(0);
    return (lowercase.equals("quit") 
           || (input.length() <= 1 && start == 'q'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks user207421, I was able to see the reason why 4 times ""(blank lines) were there. After I typed "test" I hit enter and because of that "\r\n" characters got into the input stream linked to the console. And while reading one byte at a time, at the end each of these characters were read and printed using println() of PrintStream i.e. '\r' was printed which is the first blank line and due to println() second blank line was there and the same goes while printing '\n'.